# dynamic number of axis in google line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I made a google line chart using the following options.

```
var options = {
                pointSize: 10,
                pointShape: 'circle',
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                legend: {position: 'none'},
                vAxis: {
                    viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                    viewWindow: {min: 0},
                    gridlines: {color: '#CCCCCC'},
                    textStyle: {color: '#444444'}
                },
                hAxis: {
                    viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                    viewWindow: {min: 0},
                    textStyle: {color: '#444444'}
                },
                chartArea: {left: 40, top: 10, width: 900, height: 150},
                colors: ['#FF9900', '#2A96FF', '#424242'],
                animation: {duration: 1000, easing: 'out'},
                smoothLine: true,
                tooltip: {isHtml: true}
            };
```

This line chart was generated using the above options.

[image: line chart]

When the values are changes the number of x axes is always 5. How can i set this to be dynamic so that there will be no decimal labels/values in the y axis.

For the above example i need only 0 and 1. 0.25, 0.50 and 0.75 are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can provide your own tick marks for either axis...

```
vAxis: {
    ticks: [0, 1],
    ...
```